# queryset filtering via a list of query values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A beginner django question...

Here's a JSON response...

```
"data": [
{
    "type": "Subject",
    "id": "0",
    "attributes": {
        "created": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "modified": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "subject_code": "A&H",
        "subject_name": "AH",
        "subject_short_name": "A & HUM"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "organization": {
            "data": {
                "type": "Organization",
                "id": "61"
            }
        },
        "created_user": {
            "data": null
        },
        "last_updated_user": {
            "data": null
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8001/v1/subject_owner/0"
    }
},
```

The above response is coming from a serializer

```py
queryset = Subject.objects.all()
```

I have a query which is

```
http://localhost:8001/v1/subject_owner?owner_ids=62,63
```

So, how do we write a filtering condition for the owner_ids as a list? The response should have only the results where the owner_ids match organization_id. I have tried few:

```py
queryset.filter(organization__in=[owner_id_list])
```

and

```py
queryset.filter(organization=owner_id_list)
```

and obviously they don't work. Any help will be appreciated.

FYI, here's the model class...

```py
class SubjectManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, subject_code):
        return self.get(subject_code=subject_code)


class Subject(get_subject_base_class(Organization)):

    objects = SubjectManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_code

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.subject_code,)
```

Comment: show your model

Comment: I think what you're missing is that you need to convert `owner_ids` into a list of integers. The key here is probably going to be splitting on the commas (python strings have a convenient `.split()` call for this purpose).

Comment: Your first attempt created a list within a list. Just do `queryset.filter(organization__in=owner_id_list)`. If that doesn't work, show exactly how you're defining `owner_id_list`.

Comment: @JamesAylett - you are right. I was not passing the id correctly, a little bit of conversion from string to int list helped.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, your suggestion worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make something like that:

```
owner_id_list = [62, 63]
Subject.objects.filter(organization_id__in=owner_id_list)
```